# How to parse "img src" tag in using SAXparser in android from a Local XML file

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

```
<description>
div class=&quot;field field-type-filefield field-field-book-review-image&quot;&gt;
    &lt;div class=&quot;field-items&quot;&gt;
            &lt;div class=&quot;field-item odd&quot;&gt;
                    &lt;img  class=&quot;imagefield imagefield-field_book_review_image&quot; width=&quot;500&quot; height=&quot;741&quot; alt=&quot;&quot; src=&quot;**http://sampada.net/files/good%20earth.JPG?1327387980**&quot; /&gt;        &

</description>
```

Comment: I just want to parse the url which is "bold" please help

Comment: Does your XML really look like this? I mean, between description tag it seems your special characters are quoted..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better use DOM than SAX. Simply iterate through all elements named "img" , get the "src" attribute, build a URL and fire an AsyncTask to download the stream.

Comment: I'm just new to android.. and have done with the code but what it is showing is just the links which are in link tag ,!< and not the url which are in image class..!!
please Raffaele can you help me?

Comment: You should rephrase your question better, because currently it seems such a basic task to me, that it really can't be :) you have an XML document with embedded `<img>` tag, and you want to show the images in Android native `ImageView`s, right? Can you please update your question? Does the XML really contain `&quot;` `&gt;` and so on?

Comment: [Upload your whole XML](http://pastebin.com/), and update your question to reflect the link and also to explain the desired output (you should have a mockup, if you don't, please take the time to make even a simple one, or at least describe as carefully as possible what your app is intended to with the supplied XML)

Comment: I have uploaded my whole XML file title is "kailash XML"

Comment: @KailashPawar we cannot retrieve the file via its title... Get the URL from the browser address bar and put it somewhere!

Comment: please mail me ur mail address..!! i wil mail u the file task and everything plz.!!
I was not able to upload as i got this in Pastebin 
"You have exceeded the maximum file size of 500 kilobytes per paste. PRO users don't have this limit!"

Comment: can u please tell me ur mail address

Comment: kk.pawar98@gmail.com
mail me from ur mail plz.>! LL send u d code file and everything so u can edit and help me out

Answer (score 0):

Try the following open source library:

http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/

Following are some more HTML parser:

http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers

Comment: but its an XML file which has HTML inner tags

Comment: Please post your full XML or larger portion of XML. Please also use code formatter on the XML you post..

Comment: can u give me ur mail id so i can mail you the xml file please

Comment: Hi Kailash,  I would request you to post the relevant part of the XML in your question so that other can also see it and help you out in resolving your issue..

Comment: but d file is dam lengthy..!!
its around 900 kb

Comment: Please post only the relevant portion? Also are you able to parse the raw HTML from the XML response/file? Also please share the code that you are using to parse the XML file..

Answer (score 0):

if you only want 1 pic i would use this:

```
static final String image_URL = "http://sampada.net/files/good%20earth.JPG?1327387980";

//in the oncreate

ImageView bmImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.<<your image id from the xml>>);
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions;
bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
Bitmap bm = LoadImage(image_URL, bmOptions);
bmImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
//under the oncreate

private Bitmap LoadImage(String URL, BitmapFactory.Options options)
{       
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream in = null;       
    try {
       in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
       bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
       in.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
    }
    return bitmap;               
}

private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String strURL) throws IOException{
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    URL url = new URL(strURL);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

    try{
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)conn;
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConn.connect();

        if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    return inputStream;
}
```

hope this helps you.

Comment: that xml file has 55 url which I have to show in list..!!
The URL which is bold in code..!!
jus want to show that url..!!

Comment: i want to all 55 images in list

Comment: (TASK I GOT) Please HELP..!!
It has RSS feed data from a website. It has 55 items in it. Each item has an image url. 

Your task is to 
parse the xml file and extract the image url of each item. 
Download each image and write a single bitmap in to a cache file
Name the cache file with the url of the image
On the UI part, show a download button. On clicking it, downloads should begin. 
While downloads are in progress show an indeterminate progress bar.
When downloads are complete show a "SHOW IMAGES" button. 
On clicking this button, display the downloaded images in a 'Grid Layout'.

Comment: sorry i can'trealy help you on that one, i think what you need is some sort of xml parser ([link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/))

Comment: Just help me to parse those url and display url in list please.>!

Comment: what is the url of the rss/xml? I'll see what i can do

Comment: I mail you the xml if u want?

Comment: Keeping 55 bitmap images in memory will likely crash your app with OutOfMemoryExceptions